# adding missing data based on mean of values before and after record

Tags: r, mean, data-manipulation, missing-data, imputation

Missing data of the WT column is coded as -99. I want to replace the missing values by the average of the previous and next value of WT.

For example, missing values are at time =2 and time=3 I want to compute Time1+Time4/2 and add it on both time =2 and time =3 i.e. 5.5 will be added on both Time= 2 and 3. It should be the same for all missing values.

```
ID  TIME    WT
1   0   4
1   1   5
1   2   -99
1   3   -99
1   4   6
1   5   9
1   6   12
1   7   -99
1   8   -99
1   9   -99
1   10  -99
1   12  16
1   14  18
1   16  20
```

Comment: What if the missing values is in position 1 or the last position? Should then remain -99?

Comment: If the missing value is at position 1 it should just take the next value in the column

Comment: Try something like `na.approx(df$WT, method = "constant", rule = 2, f = 0.5)` from `zoo` package, after converting all -99 into `NA` like this, `df$WT[df$WT ==-99]<- NA`

Comment: Check my answer. To note that `rule =2` takes care of missing values appearing in the first or last rows as it takes the value at the closest data extreme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added missing values to the first and last rows for testing:

```
data <- data.frame(ID=1,TIME=0:16,WT=4:20)
data[c(1,3,4,8,9,10,11,16,17),"WT"] <- -99
```

A somewhat inelegant approach but you could try first dealing with the possibility of missing first and last values:

```
data$WT[data$WT == -99] <- NA
missing <- which(is.na(data$WT))

if(1 %in% missing){
  data$WT[1] <- head(data$WT[!is.na(data$WT)],1)
}
if(nrow(data) %in% missing){
  data$WT[nrow(data)] <- tail(data$WT[!is.na(data$WT)],1)
}
```

Then, you could find the start and ends of each run of NAs with this function:

```
get_runs <- function(x){
  starts <- which(diff(x) == 1)
  y <- rle(x)
  len <- y$lengths[y$values==TRUE]
  ends <- starts + len+1
  return(list(starts=starts,len=len,ends=ends, i=1:length(starts)))
}

r <- get_runs(is.na(data$WT))
```

Finally, loop through the missing values and fill them:

```
for(i in r$i){
  idx <- seq(r$starts[i]+1,r$ends[i]-1,1)
  data$WT[idx] <- (data$WT[r$starts[i]] + data$WT[r$ends[i]])/2
}

data
   ID TIME   WT
1   1    0  5.0
2   1    1  5.0
3   1    2  6.5
4   1    3  6.5
5   1    4  8.0
6   1    5  9.0
7   1    6 10.0
8   1    7 12.5
9   1    8 12.5
10  1    9 12.5
11  1   10 12.5
12  1   11 15.0
13  1   12 16.0
14  1   13 17.0
15  1   14 18.0
16  1   15 18.0
17  1   16 18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the illustration of my comment as an answer:

```
library(readr)
library(zoo)

df <- read_table("ID TIME WT
1   0   4
1   1   5
1   2   -99
1   3   -99
1   4   6
1   5   9
1   6   12
1   7   -99
1   8   -99
1   9   -99
1   10  -99
1   12  16
1   14  18
1   16  20")

df$WT[df$WT ==-99]<- NA
na.approx(df$WT, method = "constant", rule = 2, f = 0.5)
```

Output:

```
[1]  4.0  5.0  5.5  5.5  6.0  9.0 12.0 14.0 14.0 14.0 14.0 16.0 18.0 20.0
```